# how to get a byte[] representation from a IP in String form in Java

Tags: java, arrays, ip

Suppose I have the IP stored in a String:

String ip = "192.168.2.1"

and I want to get the byte array with the four ints.
How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Something like this:

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.1");
byte[] bytes = ip.getAddress();
for (byte b : bytes) {
    System.out.println(b & 0xFF);
}
```

Comment: oh and btw the masking with 0xFF is for values over 127

Comment: in this case, developer have to handle UnknownHostException

Comment: From the javadoc: "If a literal IP address is supplied, only the validity of the address format is checked."
Doh, of course you still have to catch it :(

Answer (score 4):

Each number is a byte, so in your case the appropriate byte[] would be { 192, 168, 2, 1 }.

To be more specific, if you have the string, you first have to split it by the "."s and then parse a byte from each resulting string.

Comment: A byte has a maximum value of 127. How can you put 192 in this array?

Comment: If only there were an unsigned byte type in java.

Comment: There is a library from google - Guava. Add it and use like this:  import com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes

Comment: @eternay it is (-64) & 0xFF == 192, -64 == (byte)192

Comment: The most efficient way. It needs only 4 bytes.

Comment: I love this comment section, the most basic conversion and someone recommended using a library

Answer (score -1):

This works well for me (Kotlin):

```
    open fun reachable(host: String?): Boolean { // 'host' is string, e.g., "177.111.155.11"
    return try {
        val ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host)  // get IP address
        ipAddress.isReachable(2000)         // Is it reachable? T or F
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
            myNote("MyWX LAN Reachable Error", e.message!!) // Display error
        }
        false
    }
}
```